# Javascript charset encoding

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8

A client asked for a web crawler which analysis his website and generates a CSV file with some info from the website, but I'm having encoding issues.

I inspected the page and I can see that the `Content-Type` header is set to `"text/html; charset=utf-8"` and the meta tag for `Content-Type` has the same value.

I use simple string concatenation to generate the results, as in `CONTENT += line + '\r\n';` and, when ready, I prompt a file download:

```
var data = new Blob([CONTENT], { type: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' });
saveAs(data, 'crawler.csv');
```

I would expect the encoding to be correct, as all content is using UTF-8 encoding, but it isn't, and I still get some improper encoding, somehow, as in `RADIOFREQUÃNCIA`, where it should read `RADIOFREQUÊNCIA`. In most cases accents and diacritics are replaced by `Ã`.

I tried using several encoding/decoding methods but to no effect. Anybody has some recommendations?

Comment: Send the data *tagged as the encoding it physically is in.* Setting Content-Type to"foo/bar; charset=utf-8" does not magically make the data UTF-8. (Your observations suggest that you actually send data as an 8-bit encoding.)

Comment: I didn't write the website, how can I know which encoding it's actually in?

Comment: You can only look at the bytes that go over the wire and compare them to encoding charts. If the Content-Type header matches the data, all is well on the client side on its own and you wouldn't notice anything of it. If it doesn't... then stuff is already broken on the server's end and there is really little you can do about it on the client.

Comment: But if so how does the browser display the data correctly? Is it ignoring the tags? I've been assuming that it has something to do with Blob, no?

Comment: There is too little information (and code) in your question to assess what's really going on. Internally all Javascript strings are Unicode. So breakage can only occur while interpreting an incoming byte stream as characters (and, to a lesser extent, while writing an in-memory string to an output byte stream that is not in a Unicode encoding). So to find out what's going on, the first thing to do is to use a tool like Wireshark to inspect the physical bytes in the HTTP packets the server sends.

Comment: I thank you for your help, but I just solved the problem... And it's one that I would have never guessed: I used a different minifier !! It seemed odd that everything worked properly except this... I decided to try another minifier "just because" and bam, solved. Again, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

As odd as it might seem, using a different minifier solved the problem. I was using [this](http://jscompress.com) one and then, just because, I decided to try [this](http://javascript-minifier.com) one. Problem solved.

Comment: I recommend the [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home). (Still, a minifier should by right not make a difference, I would spend some time investigating the root cause.)

Comment: I'll keep that one in my bookmarks. Indeed it shouldn't, and I just experienced what an headache it can be when that happens. I actually got curious as to why this happened, but inspecting minified code is quite troublesome and I don't have that kind of time to give. Oh well =)